# Движение точки по заданной траектории

Tags: c#

Есть программа, которая рисует траекторию по формуле. Далее соответственно нужно создать точку которая будет по этой траектории двигаться... В этом собственно и проблема. Вроде как нужно оперировать с таймером, но как это вообще все реализовать непонятно.

Сама программа:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication13
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Trajectory cs;
    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        const int count = 50;

        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
        Point[] ptf = new Point[count];
        pictureBox1.Image = bmp;

        cs.Drow(Graphics.FromImage(bmp));
        cs.dubFScale = (double)trackBar1.Value / (double)(trackBar1.Maximum - trackBar1.Minimum);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        trackBar1.Minimum = 0;
        trackBar1.Maximum = 10;
        trackBar1.Value = (trackBar1.Minimum + trackBar1.Maximum) / 2;   
        cs = new Trajectory();

        cs.cx = pictureBox1.Width / 2;
        cs.cy = pictureBox1.Width / 2;
         cs.dubFScale = (double)trackBar1.Value/(double)(trackBar1.Maximum-trackBar1.Minimum);


    }
```

И класс Trajectory

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Drawing;

 namespace WindowsFormsApplication13
{
   public class Trajectory 
{

    public int cx { get; set; }
    public int cy { get; set; }
    public const int count = 50;
    public int k = 5;

   public int intFRadius =20;
   public double dubFScale { get; set; }

   public  void Drow(Graphics g)
{  
    Point[] ptf = new Point[count];


        double f = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < ptf.Length; i = i + 1)
        {
            ptf[i].X = (int)(cx + intFRadius * dubFScale* (k - 1) * (Math.Cos(f) + (Math.Cos((k - 1) * f)) / (k - 1)));
            ptf[i].Y = (int)(cy + intFRadius * dubFScale * (k - 1) * (Math.Sin(f) - (Math.Sin((k - 1) * f)) / (k - 1)));
            f = f + 2 * Math.PI / count;




        }

        g.DrawPolygon(Pens.Black, ptf);

        g.Dispose();
}
}
}
```